# Problems reading an empty cell from Excel with Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

882 / 5.000
Resultados de tradução
I'm trying to test the required fields of a form and for that I'm reading the data from an Excel spreadsheet, leaving the cell of the spreadsheet that corresponds to the field in the form unfilled. The problem is that Robot reads the empty cell as None and instead of leaving the field empty in the form, it is writing the string None which is different from empty. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to make Robot bring empty or make None empty when inputting the form?

```
${Username} Read From Cell (1,{counter})
Input Text <locator> ${Username}
```

Imagine that the cell is empty, in this case it returns a None for the variable ${Username} and in this case instead of leaving the field empty, RB inserts None in the Username field and the test fails, as I am waiting for a message of the type : The Username field cannot be left blank.

Answer (score 0):

To Avoid this, add condition like below before you execute any keywords

```
Run Keyword IF    "${cell_value}" != "None"    Input Text     ${xpath}    ${cell_value}
```